# How to add new line character to pdfcomment popup?

Tags: pdf, pdfcomment

I cannot seem to figure out how to separate lines in the text of a `pdfcomment` (`\pdfmarkupcomment`). I tried different standard representations, like `\n`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment{$1+1$}{first line second line}%shows lines together
%{first line\n second line} not working: undefined command \n
%{first line/n second line} /n ignored
\end{document}
```

a similar solution for the `tab` character (if possible) will be appreciated.

(note: if my memory doesn't fail, I think `\pdfmarginpar` did allow `\n` to represent the new line)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [`pdfcomment` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pdfcomment) you are looking for `\textCR`. The tab character can be given as `\textHT`, and there is also `\textLF` for a line feed. (Manual for v2.3, page 10.) Certain for me

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
\pdfmarkupcomment{$1+1$}{first line\textCR second line}
\end{document}
```

works when viewed in Adobe Reader.

Comment: Any reason why ``\\`` or ``\newline`` wasn't redefined in `pdfcomment`?